# Is there a way to pass `CTE` temporary result to function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have long [`CTE` query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5133205697d121dc9bcb063ba3380d66) with similar parts:

```sql
_saldo_end as (
    SELECT
      *,
      coalesce( start_debet, 0 ) -coalesce( start_kredit, 0 )
      +coalesce( oborot_deb, 0 ) -coalesce( oborot_kred,  0 ) as _saldo_end
    FROM saldo_start ss
    FULL JOIN schet_oborot( (select * from _schet), daterange(
         (select * from _curr_day),
        ((select * from _curr_day) +interval '1day')::date
    )) o USING ( analitid1 )
),

saldo_end as (
    select *,
      CASE WHEN _saldo_end > 0 THEN  _saldo_end ELSE 0 END as end_debet,
      CASE WHEN _saldo_end < 0 THEN -_saldo_end ELSE 0 END as end_kredit
    from _saldo_end
)
```

I want to create function for this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schet_saldo_end( _schet tbuhschet, _period daterange )
RETURNS table( _table setof, analitid1 int, oborot_deb numeric, oborot_kred numeric )
LANGUAGE sql AS $$
WITH
_saldo_start as (
    SELECT
      *,
      coalesce( start_debet, 0 ) -coalesce( start_kredit, 0 )
      +coalesce( oborot_deb, 0 ) -coalesce( oborot_kred,  0 ) as _saldo_end
    FROM _table ss  <<---- I do not know how to pass SETOF/TABLE
    FULL JOIN schet_oborot( (select * from _schet), _period ) o USING ( analitid1 )
),

select analitid1,
  CASE WHEN _saldo_end > 0 THEN  _saldo_end ELSE 0 END as start_debet,
  CASE WHEN _saldo_end < 0 THEN -_saldo_end ELSE 0 END as start_kredit
from _saldo_start
$$
```

So my `CTE` will look like:

```sql
WITH

saldo_init as (
    select
      analitid1,
      sumdeb  as start_debet,
      sumkred as start_kredit
    from saldoanal
    where  schet  = (select * from _schet)
      and nyear  = extract( year  from (select * from _prev_mon) )
      and nmonth = extract( month from (select * from _prev_mon) )
),



saldo_start as (
    select *
    from schet_saldo_end( 'saldo_init', 681, daterange( '2020-06-01', '2020-06-10' ) )
),


saldo_end as (
    select *
    from schet_saldo_end( 'saldo_start', 681, daterange( '2020-06-10', '2020-06-11' ) )
),

select * from saldo_end;
```

My problem here is that `saldo_start` and `saldo_init` are not real tables, so I can not pass theirs names.

Is there a way to pass `CTE` temporary result to function or refer to some `CTE` so I can select from it?

**UPD**

Probably one of solution is to insert CTEs result into TEMP TABLE, and pass name of this TEMP TABLE into function. But I can not imagine yet how to complete this

Comment: You cannot do that.  The CTEs are not in the name space of the function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes, but probably we can pass a referrence to it? In current `CTE` we can refer its parts. I suppose that is some sort of pointer. So we can pass that pointer to functions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it is not possible to pass `CTEs` result to function.
In deed that is just some `C` pointer to some data, I assume.

But we can store `CTEs` result into temporary table then refer this `TEMP TABLE` from our function.

Function is defined as:

```sql
--CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schet_saldo_end( _tbl anyelement, _schet tbuhschet, _period daterange )
--RETURNS SETOF anyelement
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schet_saldo_end( _tbl regclass, _schet tbuhschet, _period daterange )
RETURNS table( analitid1 int, start_debet numeric, start_kredit numeric )
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT ('
    WITH
    _saldo_start as (
        SELECT
          *,
          coalesce( start_debet, 0 ) -coalesce( start_kredit, 0 )
          +coalesce( oborot_deb, 0 ) -coalesce( oborot_kred,  0 ) as _saldo_end
        FROM %1$I ss
        FULL JOIN schet_oborot( $1, $2 ) o USING ( analitid1 )
    )
    select analitid1,
      CASE WHEN _saldo_end > 0 THEN  _saldo_end ELSE 0 END as start_debet,
      CASE WHEN _saldo_end < 0 THEN -_saldo_end ELSE 0 END as start_kredit
    from _saldo_start
', /* pg_typeof( _tbl ) */ _tbl ) USING _schet, _period;
END $$
```

And finally query:
**NOTICE** `BEGIN` is mandatory!

```sql
BEGIN;
create temp table xxx
on commit drop as

WITH
_schet    AS ( select 681::numeric(6,2)    as schet                  ),
_curr_day AS ( select '2020-06-10'::date   as cd                     ),
_curr_mon AS ( select '2020-06-01'::date   as cm                     ),
_prev_mon AS ( select cd -interval '1mon'  as pm      from _curr_day ),



saldo_init as (
    select
      analitid1,
      sumdeb  as start_debet,
      sumkred as start_kredit
    from saldoanal
    where  schet  = (select * from _schet)
      and nyear  = extract( year  from (select * from _prev_mon) )
      and nmonth = extract( month from (select * from _prev_mon) )
)

select * from saldo_init;

create temp table yyy
on commit drop as
select * from schet_saldo_end( 'xxx', 681, daterange( '2020-06-01', '2020-06-10' ) );

select * from schet_saldo_end( 'yyy', 681, daterange( '2020-06-10', '2020-06-11' ) );
COMMIT;
```

Despite on I resolve my problem (yes, ugly, but it works =) )
Question still is open:

Is this possible to pass `saldo_init` to function:

```
WITH saldo_init as ( ... )
select * from schet_saldo_end( 'saldo_init', ... );
```

**UPD**
Because `saldo_init` is just query and when we pass it into function **which returns `QUERY`**
(I think this is a key thing which allow steps I am talking about)

So here `schet_saldo_end` is just expand `saldo_init` like `SELECT fn( t.* )` expanded into `SELECT fn( t.a ), fn( t.b )`.

so

```sql
saldo_start as (
    select *
    from schet_saldo_end( 'saldo_init', 681, daterange( '2020-06-01', '2020-06-10' ) )
),
```

would be just:

```sql
saldo_start as (
    select *
    from ( 

    -- schet_saldo_end starts here
    -- ##########
    _saldo_start as (
        SELECT
          *,
          coalesce( start_debet, 0 ) -coalesce( start_kredit, 0 )
          +coalesce( oborot_deb, 0 ) -coalesce( oborot_kred,  0 ) as _saldo_end
        FROM ( 

      --saldo_init starts here
      select
        analitid1,
        sumdeb  as start_debet,
        sumkred as start_kredit
      from saldoanal
      where  schet  = (select * from _schet)
        and nyear  = extract( year  from (select * from _prev_mon) )
        and nmonth = extract( month from (select * from _prev_mon) )
      --saldo_init end

) ss
        FULL JOIN schet_oborot( 681, daterange( '2020-06-01', '2020-06-10' ) ) o USING ( analitid1 )
    )
    select analitid1,
      CASE WHEN _saldo_end > 0 THEN  _saldo_end ELSE 0 END as start_debet,
      CASE WHEN _saldo_end < 0 THEN -_saldo_end ELSE 0 END as start_kredit
    from _saldo_start

    --#############
    --schet_saldo_end END
) )
```

This final query can be folded too as original `CTEs`. This "function call" could be expanded as:

```sql
WITH

saldo_init as (
    select
      analitid1,
      sumdeb  as start_debet,
      sumkred as start_kredit
    from saldoanal
    where  schet  = (select * from _schet)
      and nyear  = extract( year  from (select * from _prev_mon) )
      and nmonth = extract( month from (select * from _prev_mon) )
),



--saldo_start as (
--    select *
--    from schet_saldo_end( 'saldo_init', 681, daterange( '2020-06-01', '2020-06-10' ) )
--),

_saldo_end as (
    SELECT
      *,
      coalesce( start_debet, 0 ) -coalesce( start_kredit, 0 )
      +coalesce( oborot_deb, 0 ) -coalesce( oborot_kred,  0 ) as _saldo_end
    FROM saldo_init ss -- <<<< NOTICE HERE we refer `saldo_init`
    FULL JOIN schet_oborot( 681, daterange( '2020-06-01', '2020-06-10' )) o USING ( analitid1 )
),

saldo_end as (
    select *,
      CASE WHEN _saldo_end > 0 THEN  _saldo_end ELSE 0 END as end_debet,
      CASE WHEN _saldo_end < 0 THEN -_saldo_end ELSE 0 END as end_kredit
    from _saldo_end
),

saldo_start as (
  select * from saldo_end
)
```

Because `schet_saldo_end` is embed into main `CTE` query we can refer `saldo_init` ;-) (see above)
And none rules are broken. Probably in PostgreSQL should be implemented this special optimization for function returning `QUERY`.

Hope everybody now understands my idea.

Comment: NO, that is not possible. The CTE is not something you can pass, in the above you would pass the string 'saldo_init' to your function NOT the evaluation of it.  Your earlier comment " but probably we can pass a reference to it"  is incorrect. It does not have an independently referecnce and may actually be folded into the main query itself. See Ppostgres [WITH Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) documentation and [Introduction to PostgreSQL common table expressions](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/)   tutorial

Comment: @Belayer: From link you gave: `A common table expression is a temporary result set which you can reference within another SQL statement`. `saldo_init` in my example also can be folded. I do not see any restrictions for that. See updated answer

Comment: And that SQL statement MUST follow immediately or cascade into another CTE. At any rate there must be a SQL statement following. They are processed collectively, they cannot b separated.

Comment: @Belayer: yes, I agree with this.